# Degree of composition extension field, given disjoint subfields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a field extension with $K \subset N,M \subset L$, such that $N \cap M = K$, does it hold that $[NM :K] = [N : K][M : K]?$

Where to compositon $NM$ is defined as $K(N \cup M)$.

My intuition says yes, but I don't know how to prove the statement.

Comment: What do you mean by $NM$?

Comment: No. Take $K=\mathbb Q$, $M=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$, $N=\mathbb Q(\varepsilon_3\sqrt[3]2)$, where $\varepsilon_3$ is the third primitive root of $1$.

Comment: I don't think $K(N \cup M)$ makes sense without an ambient field.

Comment: @KennyLau I added the ambient field.

Comment: @SMM Is it true that $N\cap M=K$?

Comment: @GuusPalmer $N\cap M=\mathbb Q$. You can see this by the chain rule because $[N:\mathbb Q]=[M:\mathbb Q]=3$ is prime, so the only possibility is that $N\cap M=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @SMM can you formulate it as an answer, and elaborate further, because it is not clear why you say the only possibility is that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $K=\mathbb Q$, $M=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ and $N=\mathbb Q(\varepsilon_3\sqrt[3]2)$, where $\varepsilon_3$ is the third primitive root of unity.

Clearly, $MN=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\varepsilon_3)$. By calculating degrees of chains $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\subset \mathbb(\sqrt[3]2,\varepsilon_3)$ and $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb Q(\varepsilon_3)\subset \mathbb(\sqrt[3]2,\varepsilon_3)$ we get $[MN:\mathbb Q]=6$.

Since $M$ is a real field and $N$ is not, $M\neq N$, so $\mathbb Q\subseteq M\cap N\subsetneq M$. Since $[M:\mathbb Q]=3$ (minimal polynomial is $x^3-2$) is prime, by the chain rule $[M\cap N:\mathbb Q]=1$, i.e. $M\cap N=\mathbb Q$. Also $[N:\mathbb Q]=3$ (minimal polynomial is $x^3-2$).